# Is this question too open?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I am thinking about asking a question, but not sure if it is too open.

I find myself always purchasing games that have similar game mechanics. I prefer worker-placement games, and railroad tycoon type games and these games borrow from each other in terms of how the game plays.

What I want to know is what other type of game mechanics really make a game more interesting, increase the strategic element and really *make* the game what it is.

I appreciate that this question maybe seen as quite subjective, but it is a genuine question that I really would appreciate the answer on. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just try asking the question, fleshed out with a little more detail, and see what kind of responses you get. If your question is really too subjective, people will vote to close. If it's OK but could be improved, people can comment. And if it's good, you should start to get some good answers; if you're getting good answers, then that probably means the question is fine.

This site does have a somewhat higher percentage of subjective questions than other SE sites (at least, the ones I'm familiar with like SO). I think that's OK, as long as you try to keep in mind the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) guidelines. Make sure you provide enough detail to focus the discussion, and not something overly broad like "what are the best mechanics"; make sure your question inspires explanations of why and how, not just simple one liners for people to vote on.

Comment: This sounds like good advice.  We've still got a long ways to go in beta.  It's a great time to try out different things.  Just don't take personal offense if a question gets closed out!  I think that if we aren't closing many questions then we are probably not testing our limits enough.